# Method to return each objects as self object

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a problem with a list in Python. I want that my `Category` has a method to return me all categories in databases. So this is my code

```
class Category(Database)::

    # other methods here

    def find_by_id(self,  id_to_find ):
        sql_command = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1"
        self.cursor.execute( sql_command , data )
        return self.is_data_exists( self.cursor )

    # to check if cursor have at less one row
    def is_data_exists(self , cursor):
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
             return False
        else:
            # if data exists, we set the object with values
            self.id = data[0]
            self.name = data[1]
            return self


    def all(self):
        all_item = []
        self.cursor.execute( "SELECT id FROM categories" )

        for row in self.cursor.fetchall() :
            item = self.find_by_id(row[0])
            print( item.describe() )
            # problem here
            all_item.append(item)

        return all_item



Category().add("WEB")
Category().add("PYT")
Category().add("TEST")
Category().add("HELL")


for category in Category().all():
    print(category.describe())
```

So `print( item.describe() )` return :

```
Category #1 named *TEST*
Category #2 named *WEB*
Category #3 named *PYT*
Category #4 named *HELL*
```

But `Category().all()` return :

```
Category #4 named *HELL*
Category #4 named *HELL*
Category #4 named *HELL*
Category #4 named *HELL*
```

What goes wrong? It seem be like `self` object change in array...

Comment: What is `self.find_by_id(row[0])`? It looks it is returning references to the same object.

Comment: Yes it is. I update the class definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find myself a trick today. In fact I have only to call `Category()` and not `self` method to instance "another self" object into this object. Here the result:

```
class Category():
    database = Database(database_file_name)

    # other methods here

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        """return each categories présents in database"""
        cls.database.cursor.execute( "SELECT id FROM categories" )

        for id in self.cursor.fetchall() :
            yield Category.find_by_id(id[0])
```

I don't know if it's strange, but it's do the job! Thanks you **spectras** for your help!

Answer (score 2):

So, let's break it down:

- `is_data_exists` returns a reference to `self` after setting some member variables.
- `find_by_id` returns the reference returned by `is_data_exists`, so a reference to `self` as well.

Then:

```
item = self.find_by_id(row[0])
```

Because of the way the value is returned, this is equivalent to `item = self`.
Thus, `all_item.append(item)` appends a reference to `self` to your `all_item` list.

So your list actually is `[self, self, self, self]`.

The root of the problem is a bit further. You have a structural problem. You define:

```
class Category(Database):
```

However, inheriting a class means *“X is a Y”*. Here, you say *“Category is a Database”*.

But `Category` is **not** a database, so this is inherently wrong. `Category` should just be an `object`, or perhaps a `Record`, if you need some common methods. Then for every row returned by the database, you would instantiate a `Category` and add it to the list.

But by all means, unless you're doing this as an exercise, use a proper database abstraction module such as SQL alchemy, it will save you loads of time.

Comment: You're right, so I will rename my class as : `class Category(Record):` and put all common methods in `class Record:`. But how you can instanciate multiple self object class in class herself?

Comment: Two options: 1) you don't, you have a separate class do it. Or 2) you use a [class method](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods). Option 2 is only if it does not need state. Try to check out how Django's or SQLalchemy's database abstraction are structured, they both have a pretty solid way of doing things.